# is there any reason to use a property for an ivar that is only being used internally in a class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

Is there any reason to use a property for an ivar that is only being used internally in a class?

I can see that use of properties in objective-c for a class assist other classes accessing the instance variables, however for just internal usage of an instance variable is there any benefit/need to use a property for it?  In fact for the property you have to be "self." before it to access it it seems, as opposed to just the name of the instance variable.

Perhaps I should break up this question into:

- for instance variables that represent IBOutlet controls (in case this is special)
- any other instance variable you may need across the methods of a class to assist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.  If you need to change the value of this variable at times other than `-init` and `-dealloc`, using an `@property` means you can let the compiler handle the memory management for you.

Comment: Hi Dave - didn't quite get what you meant here - you still have to release properties in the dealloc method I've been assuming?

Comment: I would suggest adding any such `@property`s in a class extension.

Comment: @Greg yep, you'll still need to `-release` in `-dealloc` (like normal).  But internally, you'll be able to do `[self setFoo:newFoo];`, and all of the memory management of releasing the old value and retaining the new value will be handled for you. This is very very very useful.  @Richard's suggestion of putting the declaration in a class extension is a great one.

Comment: +1 (+10 if I could). Encapsulating memory management is critical. The alternative is to scatter it all over the place, throughout your code, which makes it a nightmare to debug when (not if) you forget a required retain or release somewhere. The use of @property and dot syntax is somewhat incidental though; it's the use of setter methods that's critical here, not the means of creating them. Hand-rolled setter methods would have the same benefit with respect to encapsulation.

Comment: ok thanks - kind of a shame that you have to type "self." before using a property though - or is there a +ve spin on this I'm missing?

Comment: @Greg if you leave off the `self.`, then you're just accessing the ivar directly, which totally bypasses the property setter.  If you'd prefer, you can do `[self setFoo:newFoo];` instead of `self.foo = newFoo;`

Answer (score 1):

I generally don't use the interface builder, but I think you always want properties for your IBOutlets. I just answered a question by a guy that got bad access because he didn't. You could possibly do without (I don't know), but memory management becomes easier.

As far as any other instance variable goes the only reason to use properties is to make memory management easier:

```
self.object = newObject;
```

replaces

```
[object release];
object = [newObject retain];
```

If you don't intend to use your property outside of the class, you could declare it in your .m file, just as you do with private methods. That way other classes will be unaware of the existence of your property.

Comment: `object = [newObject retain]`.

Comment: ... and **that** is why accessors are so important. It's all too easy to forget such things when we write it by hand! :-)

Comment: @Sherm I didn't realize it, but I was proving a point, wasn't I? :)